# Will LessPHP work on PHP 5.1.6?

Tags: php, less

I am trying to include [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) to my server which works under PHP 5.1.6. On localhost (PHP Version 5.3.8) proper css was created, but on remote it seems not to work. On project page I cannot find any server requirements, so I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or it is my server issue? Has anyone dealt with similar problem?

Comment: It looks like this is a compiler, so could you not just generate at build time, and just deliver the raw results on your remote server without any LessPHP?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it: 5.1.2 is the minimum, from a web search that got me [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-less/). That said, are you sure you want to be using such an old version? I'd not use anything less than 5.2.4 these days, and even that is out of support.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any influence on updating to newer PHP version. I will probably give up using LessPHP with that project.

Comment: Can you not just 'compile' your CSS when you do your build/commit? Also, see if you are getting any PHP errors in your logs. Lastly there may be a support community for this project - get in touch with them.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on your error reporting and see if there's an error being thrown!